# C# Grab element attribute by class name

Tags: c#, html, web, element, screen-scraping

So I want to grab the value of `data-sitekey` from the snippet below.

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LdC0iQUAAAAAOYmRv34KSLDe-7DmQrUSYJH8eB_"></div>
```

I've tried using a Web Browser as well as the **HtmlAgilityPack** but no luck.
This is my code:

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();

HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(url);

var headerNames = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='g-recaptcha']").ToList();

foreach (var item in headerNames)
{
    string hrefValue = item.GetAttributeValue("data-sitekey", string.Empty);
    Console.WriteLine(hrefValue);
}
```

Comment: What isn't working? :)

Comment: @sniperd It just returns 'The operation has timed out'

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this   `string hrefValue = Attributes["data-sitekey"]`

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
                HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(url);

                var headerNames = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='g-recaptcha']").ToList();

                foreach (var item in headerNames)
                {
                    string hrefValue = Attributes["data-sitekey"]
                    Console.WriteLine(hrefValue);
                }
```